# Appropriate SE site for personal technical support?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What would be the most appropriate Stack Exchange site (if any) to ask for support about a certain computer program?

I was thinking Super User, but I am not fully sure - can someone please tell me which I should use?

Comment: Can you clarify what  you mean by "personal technical support"?

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags Questions that ask for support with a program, basically.

Comment: What kind of support? Personal support questions are off-topic on Stack Exchange, but you may be able to put it as a proper question

Comment: It depends on the question you have I guess. I tend to go with: [Stack Overflow is not a proxy for customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128579#128579), but it **might** be suited for SU (again it's all depending on your question).

Comment: Actually it can be anything now that I read it again... :P

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags General support, ie. troubleshooting help, questions on how to do x, and such.

Comment: Most programs have a manual. I suggest you start there. Or look into the support options of the specific program. Most ( / all?) SE sites aren't really meant for **personal** technical support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Superuser FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

The most important point in the "Don't Ask" section, in terms of computer software, is this:

> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Thus, if your question is about an actual, real problem that you're facing with a computer program, and you've done research on the topic that you can document in your question, and if you can clearly state what you've tried so far and include all the relevant details about your unique situation, then your question will more than likely be on topic on Superuser.

Just be sure to **search first** so that you don't post a duplicate.